# PHP Multidimensional array combinations

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Below is My Array. I want to make all possible combinations of array whose sum is equal to some number(e.g 20). The super parent array is continent and it's child array is it's countries and countries child array is its respective cities. i want to get all combinations of countries whose cities sum of days_range equal to some number(e.g 20). This is just a single continent array. it may be possible that the array is for other continents  are also available.

```html
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [city_name] => Baku
                            [country_id] => 10
                            [country_name] => Azerbaijan
                            [days_range] => 5
                            [continent_id] => 1
                        )

                  [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 43
                            [city_name] => Lahıc
                            [country_id] => 10
                            [country_name] => Azerbaijan
                            [days_range] => 5
                            [continent_id] => 1
                        )
                )

            [23] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 42
                            [city_name] => Vientiane
                            [country_id] => 23
                            [country_name] => Laos
                            [days_range] => 7
                            [continent_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 47
                            [city_name] => Vang Vieng
                            [country_id] => 23
                            [country_name] => Laos
                            [days_range] => 3
                            [continent_id] => 1
                        )

                )

            [20] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 37
                            [city_name] => Tamsui District
                            [country_id] => 20
                            [country_name] => Taiwan
                            [days_range] => 1
                            [continent_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 35
                            [city_name] => Taipei
                            [country_id] => 20
                            [country_name] => Taiwan
                            [days_range] => 3
                            [continent_id] => 1
                        )

                )
              [22] => Array
                (
                     [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 46
                            [city_name] => Maolin District
                            [country_id] => 20
                            [country_name] => Taiwan
                            [days_range] => 3
                            [continent_id] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 36
                            [city_name] => Tainan
                            [country_id] => 20
                            [country_name] => Taiwan
                            [days_range] => 3
                            [continent_id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Below is my expected Output.

```
Array(

    [0]=Array(

            [0]=>[10],
            [1]=>[23],
         )

    [1]=Array(

            [0]=>[10],
            [1]=>[20],
            [2]=>[22],
       )

    [2]=Array(

            [0]=>[23],
            [1]=>[20],
            [2]=>[22],
       )
)
```

Comment: Your desired output ?

Comment: Array(

    [0]=Array(

            [0]=>[10],
            [1]=>[23],
         )

    [1]=Array(

            [0]=>[10],
            [1]=>[20],
            [2]=>[22],
       )

    [2]=Array(

            [0]=>[23],
            [1]=>[20],
            [2]=>[22],
       )
)